# How to make an Android thread start only when another Android thread ends

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want this android program to have a 10 second countdown before a File is written and then read and set as the text on the MainActivity. I want the mCounterThread to finish its task before mFileThread starts. Since onPause() and onResume() may elongate the amount of required time I can't do a .sleep(milliseconds) with a fixed time. I tried thread.join() but this does not seem to work. Why? Could I use another notify/wait? Thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView mText;
private EditText mUserInput;
private CounterThread mCounterThread;
private MakingFileThread mFileThread;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    mUserInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
    mCounterThread = new CounterThread();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mCounterThread.onPause();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mCounterThread.onResume();
}

public void startCounterThread(){
    mCounterThread.start();
}

public void startMakingFileThread(String s1,String s2){
    mFileThread = new MakingFileThread(s1,s2);
    mFileThread.start();
}

public void button_handler(View v){
    String val = mUserInput.getText().toString();
    startCounterThread();
    String file = "myfile.txt";
    startMakingFileThread(val, file);//I want this to start only 
    //once mCounterThread has finished its countdown.
   }

public void updateSeconds(final long seconds){
    Runnable UIdoWork = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            String time = String.valueOf(seconds);
            mText.setText("Your file will open in " + time + " seconds");
        }
    };
    runOnUiThread(UIdoWork);
}


public void updateWriteFile(final String userText){
    Runnable UIdoWork = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            mText.setText(userText);
        }
    };
    runOnUiThread(UIdoWork);
}

private class CounterThread extends Thread{
    private int count = 10;
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private volatile boolean isRunning = true;

    public void onResume(){
        if(!isRunning){
            isRunning = true;
        }
        synchronized (lock){
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    public void onPause(){
        isRunning = false;
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void run(){
        while(count != 0){
            synchronized (lock){
                if(!isRunning)try{
                    lock.wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            updateSeconds(count--);
         }

    }
}

private class MakingFileThread extends Thread{
    private String userInput;
    private String fileName;

    public MakingFileThread(String s1,String s2){
        userInput = s1;
        fileName = s2;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(20000);//right now I have this thread
            //wait 20 seconds before it starts
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream =      openFileOutput(fileName,MODE_PRIVATE);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter((new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8")));
            writer.write(userInput);
            writer.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput( fileName );
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8")));
            String ans = reader.readLine();
            updateWriteFile(ans);
            reader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the `AsyncTask#postExecute()` method suit your needs? As stated in the android documentation:

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
>
> ...
>
> An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.

There is also a class in Android for the count down stuff, do not reinvent the wheel. See docs for [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

You can execute your File processing in the AsyncTask and on the postExecute callback do other actions required.

Comment: I agree that this would work. But is there a way to do what my question asked using solely threads? Bye the way thanks for the CountDownTimer Doc.

Comment: Of course you can. AsyncTask is made by threads behind the scences. Anyway, you can do this by starting a thread after the other one has finished, at the end of the run method. If you have also your own count down timer you can also play with Thread#isInterrupted() by interrupting a the Thread when you want to perform an action

Comment: Thanks "at the end of the run method" for CounterThread made the app work. Thanks!